# Jupyter install returns “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1

Tags: python, exception, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new to Python and have been trying to install [Jupyter](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) packages with `pip`.

My command line throws me this Exception

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\TOSHIB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-spdc68do\tornado\

Happens when I do `pip install jupyter`.  How can I solve this?

I already did `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install --upgrade setuptools`.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? It may be simpler to install anaconda and let it handle the install, as [the jupyter docs](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) suggest

Comment: Im using python 3, i'll try anaconda then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the root cause is that jupyter depends on tornado, but the tornado install is failing.

<strike>It could be a [lib64 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017155/why-is-pip-install-tornado-not-installing-the-tornado-module) and `pip install -U wheel` might do the trick.</strike>

Could also just be down to tornado requiring a C/C++ compiler you don't have installed. Anaconda comes with jupyter notebook and has a simple windows installer, so that seems like the easiest path.